# Set cookie in django-cms plugin

Tags: django, cookies, plugins, django-cms

Using Django 1.5.5, Django-CMS 2.4.2
I wrote a plugin for django-cms *(cms.plugin_base.CMSPluginBase)*. Plugin create a some form, that works fine. But I get a problem - after submitting a form - how can I set a **cookie** ?

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from poll.models import PagePoll
from poll.forms import PollForm
from django.http import HttpResponse

class PollPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    """ upload a poll  """
    model = PagePoll
    name = u'Poll'
    render_template = u"plugins/page_poll.html"

def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
    #upload poll form
    request = context['request']

    form = PollForm(instance.poll, request.POST)

    #validate the form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            #=SAVE COOKIES HERE=
    else:
        form = PollForm(instance.poll)

    context['form'] = form
    return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(PollPlugin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found here:
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2541/

The problem was that *cms-plugin* can't return a *responce* object, where **cookies** need to bet **set**... So the trick is to throw a custom exception with **HttpResponceRedirect**